# Как настроить ЧПУ seo url страниц фильтра товаров woocommerce в дополнение к permalinks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Возможно ли в WordPress сделать некоторые страницы фильтров ЧПУ и открыть их для индексации? И как это сделать?

Например, если у меня магазин товаров, и я бы хотел продвигать страницы по запросу товар+бренд.
А всего имеется 50 разных видов товаров и у каждого по несколько брендов.

Answer (score -1):

Есть решение для wordpess под поисковики.https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/seo-tile-of-tag/ Это дополнение для создания посадочных страниц к фильтру товаров woocommerce. Данное дополнение перезаписывает адреса страниц фильтра на человеко понятные url (ЧПУ или seo url). Например, до запуска было product-category/uni/?filter_firstpro=f1_raz, после - станет product-category/uni/filter-firstpro-f1_raz/

Кроме этого появилась возможность присваивать таким страницам свой title, meta-описание, и дескрипшн под заголовком. В дополнение к woocommerce чпу permalinks при использовании woocommerce seo url конкурентное преимущество в поисковиках будет гарантировано.

Comment: Весь текст ответа должен быть внутри самого ответа. Ссылка может устареть или быть удалена, а контент должен остаться тут.